# Binary Calculator

Tags: java, arrays, binary

I am trying to create binary calculator that converts integers to 8 bit binary output. 
I am lost and any help would be appreciated.
Here is my progress so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
public class Unit4 
{
    public static int convertToBinary(int baseTenIntOne)
    {
        int [] firstNum = new int [8];
        int binary = 0;
        int bvalue = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            if (baseTenIntOne % 2 == 1)
                binary += bvalue;
            else
                binary += 0;    
            bvalue *= 10;
        }
        System.out.println(binary);
        return binary;
    }
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int baseTenIntOne;
        int baseTenIntTwo;
        System.out.println("Enter a base ten number between 0 and 255, inclusive.");
        baseTenIntOne = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(baseTenIntOne);
        System.out.println("Enter a base ten number between 0 and 255, inclusive.");
        baseTenIntTwo = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(baseTenIntTwo); 
        convertToBinary(baseTenIntOne);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put this snippet in your **convertToBinary(int baseTenIntOne)** method

{

```
if (baseTenIntOne == 0)
{

    return "0";
}

String binary = "";
while (baseTenIntOne > 0) {
    int rem = baseTenIntOne % 2;
    binary = rem + binary;
    baseTenIntOne = baseTenIntOne / 2;
}
System.out.println(binary);
return binary;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method:

```
System.out.println("Enter a Integer Value:");
int h = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
String oct = Integer.toString(h,8);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Integer.toBinaryString(int i);`

And then append zeros to the beginning of the string

```
  public static String convertToBinary(int baseTenIntOne){
    String binaryRep = Integer.toBinaryString(baseTenIntOne);
    while(binaryRep.length()<8){
       binaryRep.insert(0, "0" );
    }

   return binaryRep;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgotten was doing in the for-loop:

```
baseTenIntOne /= 2;
```

So the next bit appears at the first position.